# which is faster, saving chat history in a text file and display it or using mysql db to save chat history

Tags: php, mysql, performance, chat, real-time

I am developing a chat application in mysql, jQuery.

I have read few tutorials and I want to know which way among the following makes the chat comparatively more faster and real time.
I have also tried implementing it and want to know the best possible solution.

1. save each chat entered into mysql db and display the chat from the table i get from db.
2. save each chat entered into a text file and display the content of text file as chat history each time.

or is there any other recommended way ?

Comment: too many factors can contribute to the performance of one vs the other. db location and load, filesystem type and load etc...

Comment: Orangepill : lets say, i have a load of around 300 concurrent users, and i use godaddy servers, i have no idea where the db location and filesystem godaddy follows,..if you know, then any suggestion in this case???

Comment: In that case database is probably a more performant and scalable option. 300 concurrent users would be be waiting for each other to release their file locks

Comment: i was actually thinking of creating an individual temp file for each caht session and delete it once the chat is over... in that case, would file access be faser than db access???

Comment: depending on how active the chatters are and how loaded the filesystem is.

Comment: assuming an average of 150 chat sessions with 300 participates with moderate usage you probably wouldn't notice a difference either way.

Answer (score 2):

For a real-world implementation, I wouldn't consider either one of these a good option, but it definitely could be fun to play with. Using files isn't going to scale as well as the db,well... as easily. But really, I'd look into just setting up a jabber server and play with that. Or maybe look into node.js.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by looking at node.js ? Is there another option to save the chattlogs with node ? I have the same problem ... :)